# RPC calls between C and Python, and vicecersa

Tags: python, c, linux, solaris, rpc

I have an old RPC server running in a Solaris machine. This called by quite a few RPC clients in Solaris and Linux hosts.

We want to move to a Solaris-free scenario. And the first thing we want to do is to port the RPC server to Linux, preferably using C or Python. Unfortunately, the original code uses the System V STREAMS framework for transport, and we want to get rid of it, if possible. Is there a way to create a C or Python RPC server, that substitutes the original, without having to touch the current C clients? My initial idea is that this is not possible, since the transport layer fr the new server would be fundamentally different, i.e., it will not use XTI/TIL. But just in case I'm missing something.

Thanks!